# how to pass the date dynamically for get the data for particular date?

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i am trying get records for particular date.

I have logins and logouts of employee for every day.
Now i want to show only his first login and his last logout.

So in my model i want to pass where condition where i want to pass  a date selected from date picker in my view. and want to show data of that date only.

So this is my controller:

```
 public function index()
    {

   $this->data['attendances'] = $this->attendance_m->join_data();
   //var_dump($rajan);
    $this->data['attendance_dropdown'] = $this->attendance_m->get_emp_list();
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/attendance/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
```

This is the model function :

```
   public function join_data()
   {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('daily_data2');
  $this->db->where('date_data',"2015-11-04 14:07:06");
  $this->db->order_by("date_data","DESC");
  $this->db->LIMIT(1);
  $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id');

  $query = $this->db->get();




  $res   = $query->result();        
    return $res;



 }
```

The View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
        <h2>Upload CSV To Import Users</h2>
        <!-- in the action you need to place /controller/function in our case @Attendance, @upload -->
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/attendance/upload');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>


        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">


        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="form-group">
        <h1><label for="sel1">Select list:</label></h1>
        <select name="attendance-list" id="attendance-list" class="form-control" >

        <?php foreach($attendance_dropdown as $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['emp_id'];?>"><?php echo $value['emp_name']; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>


        </select>

        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        </div>

        <h1 class="page-header">Attendance Details</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->



        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        All Calls Records
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">


        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Emp_ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Entry</th>



        </tr>
        </thead>



        <tbody>

        <?php if(count($attendances)): foreach($attendances as $attendance): ?>


        <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td><?php echo trim($attendance->emp_id,'">'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo trim($attendance->name.$attendance->last_name,'">'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo trim($attendance->date_data,'">'); ?></td>
        <td><?php trim($attendance->entry,'">'); ?> <?php if($attendance->entry >100)
        {
        echo "Logged In";
        }
        else
        {
        echo"Logged Out";
        }?>
        </td>


        </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php else: ?>

        <tr>
        <td colspan="3">We could not find any Data.</td>
        </tr>

        <?php endif; ?>



        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.table-responsive -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- /.row -->







        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
        <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
        <script src="../bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
        <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>


         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->

        <script>
          $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
          });
          </script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
        });
        });
        </script>





        <script>
        site_url="http://127.0.01/project/admin/";
        $('#attendance-list').on('change', function () {
        var select_emp_id=$(this).val();
        if(select_emp_id!=""){
        var params={};
        params["id"]= select_emp_id;
        params["name"]= select_name;
        $.ajax({type: 'POST',dateType:'json', url: site_url + 'attendance/getUserData', data: params,success: function (response) {
        //write on response logic/set employee details
        var user_data=JSON.parse(response);
        }, async: true});
        }
        });
        </script>



        <script> 
        site_url = "http://127.0.01/project/admin/"; 
        $('#attendance-list').on('change', function() { 


        var select_emp_id=$(this).val(); 
        if(select_emp_id!=""){ 
        var params={}; 
        params["id"]= select_emp_id;


        $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: site_url + 'attendance/getUserInfo', data: params, success: function(response) { 


        //write on response logic/set employee details 

        console.log(response); 
        var user_data = JSON.parse(response); 
        console.log(user_data); 
        var row = '<tr class="odd gradeX"><td>' + user_data.emp_id + '</td><td>' + user_data.name + ' ' + user_data.last_name'</td><td>' + user_data.date_data + '</td><td>' + user_data.entry + ' ' + (user_data.entry > 100?"Logged In":"Logged Out") + '</td> </tr>'; 
        $("#dataTables-example tbody").find('tr').remove(); 
        $("#dataTables-example tbody").append(row); 
        }, async: true}); 
        } 
        }); 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [CodeIgniter tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html), this shows how to get information based on data passed through.  In the example, it's from the URL.

There's an example on the tutorial of [creating news](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html) of how the model can use the POST information with the database, so you'd have something like:

```
// in the model you can get the date
$filter_date = $this->input->post('date_field'); // change the 'date_field' to your actual field name in the POST

// other query information
$this->db->where('date_data', $filter_date);

// finish the query and continue...
```

**EDIT - following a request to edit**

Based on what I have said above, and in the comments, your view will have the following part:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date_data"></p>
```

Your model will then have :

```
$filter_date = $this->input->post('date_data');
```

And on further inspection of your code, you're currently getting null passed through for this because the date_data field is outside of the `<form></form>` in your view, so it's not part of the form to be submitted.

It also looks like you're trying to reload the grid based on AJAX, which will mean your JavaScript/jQuery will need changing so it passes the date field through as part of the params.

Comment: Yeah but i am passing the date picker in my view so how will model know which date is selected

Comment: In my view i have just passed the date picker so how to know which date to be passed in model while fetching the data

Comment: Your input element with ID 'datepicker' will need to be given a name.  That will then be posted to the server on submit of the form, which is where you can use the `$this->input->post()`  part to get the value

Comment: you mean like this :<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date_data"></p> then in model i should do    $filter_date = $this->input->post('date_data');

Comment: Yes.  Adding names to input elements allows them to be accessed on submit of the form.

Comment: yes i did this: <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date_data"></p>

Comment: Then in my model i did this:  $filter_date = $this->input->post('date_data');

var_dump($filter_date);

Comment: but when i do var_dump filter_date it returns null

Comment: This doesn't work when i select any date it returns bool(false)

Comment: when i select any date there should be date submitted to the form

Comment: can u please tell me how the model will know which date was selected from the form? i also tried to post name and id but returns bool :(

Comment: When the form is submitted or the field posted, there should only be one date as there is just the one field (unless I've missed a loop).  If there is more than one date field, then you've got a different problem and it gets a little more complex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98904/discussion-between-rajan-and-gabe3886).